# Problema na implementação de uma lista encadeada - inserção de lista

Tags: c

Estou tentando realizar esta implementação em C. Estou tendo dois problemas.

Primeiro: Dentro do main, eu faço o registro dos dados que eu quero e quando vou inserir na lista eu obtenho um problema.

Segundo: Minha função de leitura de dados "imprimir_dados" dá erro ao compilar. Eu estou usando o codeblocks e aparece a seguinte mensagem "invalid type argument of '->'".

Eu parcialmente entedo que "->" é sinalização de ponteiro e que para acessar meu dado de registro não é necessário o ponteiro, já que o nodo foi acessado e estamos buscando a informação estatíca interna. Entretanto, eu gostaria de uma explicação mais detalhada se possível.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    typedef struct registro_st{         // sequência de objetos do mesmo tipo
        char login[50];
        char nome[50];
        float valor;
        struct registro *prox;
    } registro;

    typedef struct nodo_st{
        registro dado;
    struct nodo *prox;
    } nodo;

    typedef struct Lista_st{
        nodo *cabeca;
        nodo *cauda;
    int tamanho;
    } lista;


    nodo* CriarNodo(registro p){

            nodo* n;
            n = (nodo*)malloc(sizeof(nodo));
            n->dado = p;
            n->prox= NULL;
    return n;
    }

    void criarLista(lista *l){
            return NULL;
    }

    void insere_ini(lista *l, registro dado){
        nodo* novo = (nodo*)malloc(sizeof(nodo));
            if(novo=NULL){
                return 0; //falta de espaço
            };
            novo->dado = dado;
            novo->prox = l->cauda; //antigo primeiro aponta para o próximo
            l->cauda = novo; // novo nodo recebe ponteiro para começo
            return novo;



    }

    //FUNÇÕES PARA UTILIZAR NO MAIN

    void imprime_nomes(nodo* lista){            // função que imprime os valores
        nodo* p;
            for(p = lista; p != NULL; p = p->prox){
                printf("Nome eh: %s\n", p->dado->nome);
            }
    }
    void criar_registro(registro *p){
        printf("Qual login para registro:\n");
        scanf("%s", &p->login);
        printf("Qual o nome do contato:\n");
        scanf("%s", &p->nome);
        printf("Qual valor para registrar:\n");
        scanf("%f", &p->valor);
    }


    int main(){

    registro p1_main;
    lista   p2_main;
    nodo p3_main;

    char escolha;

    printf("Gostaria de registrar contatos?\n");
    printf("Digite -->>!! sim!! <<-- para registrar e -->>!! não !!<<-- para sair.\n");
    scanf("%s", &escolha);

    criarLista(&p2_main);

    do  {
        criar_registro(&p1_main); //poderia usar esta forma alternativa registro *novoRegistro = criar_registro()

        insere_ini(&p2_main, p1_main);
        }

        while(escolha != "nao");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos por partes.

Primeiro, em **imprime_nomes** o uso do *for* neste caso é uma má prática de programação, pois você não sabe o número de elementos que terá a lista de encadeada. Para tal caso, utilize o *while* dessa forma:

```
void imprime_nomes(nodo* lista) // função que imprime os valores
{ 
    nodo* p = lista;
    while (p)
    {
        printf("Nome eh: %s\n", p->dado->nome);
        p = p->prox;
    }
}
```

Segundo, o problema está na declaração da estrutura **nodo_st**. Você deve apontar o membro **dado** como um ponteiro, e não como um dado por si só. É por essa razão que estava dando o problema com a flecha de ponteiro (*->*), pois a estrutura não estava indicada como ponteiro da forma que deveria. Isto ficará dessa forma:

```
typedef struct nodo_st
{
    registro * dado;
}
```

Terceiro, o parâmetro usado no **CriaNodo** deve ser um ponteiro, e portanto deve ter asterisco antes do nome da variável:

```
nodo* CriarNodo(registro * p)
{
        nodo* n;
        n = (nodo*)malloc(sizeof(nodo));
        n->dado = p;
        n->prox= NULL;
        return n;
}
```

O mesmo ocorre na função **insere_ini**. Corrigindo, fica assim:

```
void insere_ini(lista *l, registro * dado)
{
    nodo* novo = (nodo*)malloc(sizeof(nodo));
        if(novo=NULL){
            return 0; //falta de espaço
        };
        novo->dado = dado;
        novo->prox = l->cauda; //antigo primeiro aponta para o próximo
        l->cauda = novo; // novo nodo recebe ponteiro para começo
        return novo;
}
```

Por último, também é necessário ajustar essa operação para as modificações feitas, indicando os argumentos como ponteiros:

```
insere_ini(&p2_main, &p1_main);
```

Isso ainda gerará múltiplos *Warnings* que você terá de corrigir aos poucos. Recomendo um estudo aprofundado de ponteiros, pois se trata de um dos conhecimentos mais essenciais para programar bem em C.

Comment: No caso do "imprime_nomes(nodo* lista)" existe um ponteiro "lista" que aponta para nodo e um ponteiro "p" que aponta para nodo também. Por que isso? Qual o parâmetro que imprimi deve receber?

Comment: Bem observado. Como na _imprime_nomes_ você vai iterar em uma lista encadeada para cada elemento, o correto é colocar o parâmetro **lista** da função dentro do ponteiro **p** desta forma:  `nodo *p = lista;`, ou mesmo usar o próprio parâmetro **lista** dentro da função em vez da variável **p**. As duas possibilidades são corretas. Editei a resposta conforme o indicado.